# How to make (list, dictionary) in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

How to make (list, dictionary) from:

```
n = ('banana', 5, 'apple', 400, 'orange', 250, 'peach', 300)
```

to :

```
(fruit -> price)
```

Example:

```
for..print all
    banana -> 5
    apple -> 400
    orange -> 250
    peach -> 300
```

Comment: Also, OP, your `n` is not a list but a tuple...

Comment: How to? By writing some code.

Comment: @Matthias : you are clever

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dict` and `zip`:

```
n = ('banana', 5, 'apple', 400, 'orange', 250, 'peach', 300)

print(dict(zip(n[::2],n[1::2])))
{'orange': 250, 'peach': 300, 'banana': 5, 'apple': 400}
```

`zip(n[::2],n[1::2])` creates `[('banana', 5), ('apple', 400), ('orange', 250), ('peach', 300)]` then calling dict on the result creates key/value pairings from each tuple.

More efficiently using iter to avoid slicing and creating new lists:

```
n = ('banana', 5, 'apple', 400, 'orange', 250, 'peach', 300)
it = iter(n)
print(dict(zip(it,it)))
```

To print the items:

```
for fruit, cost in dict(zip(it,it)).items():
    print("{} -> {}".format(fruit, cost))

apple -> 400
orange -> 250
banana -> 5
peach -> 300
```

If you just want  pairs just use zip:

```
for fruit, cost in zip(it,it):
    print("{} -> {}".format(fruit, cost))

banana -> 5
apple -> 400
orange -> 250
peach -> 300
```

dicts don't have order so that is why the output is in a different order between both.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, how can i make structure without `print` ?

Comment: @croutreb, not sure I understand,  I added how to print the items